# DSSP from Biopython throwing an error 'NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError''

Tags: biopython, nameerror

I'm trying to run DSSP through Biopython, a couple of months ago the code worked, however, I now get this erroe. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
>>>from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
>>>from Bio.PDB.DSSP import DSSP
>>>p=PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)
>>>st= p.get_structure('1bzq','1bzqK.pdb')
>>>model=st[0]
>>>dssp= DSSP(model,'1bzqK.pdb',dssp='dssp')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/rennes/akhila/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/DSSP.py", line 355, in __init__
except FileNotFoundError:
NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined
```

I have checked the path of dssp also by

```
user@home:~/Documents/FR_distances$ mkdssp
mkdssp 2.2.1 options:
-h [ --help ]         Display help message
-i [ --input ] arg    Input file
-o [ --output ] arg   Output file, use 'stdout' to output to screen
-v [ --verbose ]      Verbose output
--version             Print version
-d [ --debug ] arg    Debug level (for even more verbose output)
```

I have also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749328/windowserrorerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) and changed the dssp path, but still it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From [source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/e6a87268c63a6732c7cd64c9f69388f1d946f30c/Bio/PDB/DSSP.py#L51-L55):

> Note that the recent DSSP executable from the DSSP-2 package was
>   renamed from `dssp` to `mkdssp`. If using a recent DSSP release, you
>   may need to provide the name of your DSSP executable:
>   `>>> dssp = DSSP(model, '1mot.pdb', dssp='mkdssp')`

Try replacing `dssp= DSSP(model,'1bzqK.pdb',dssp='dssp')` by:

```
dssp = DSSP(model, '1bzqK.pdb', dssp='mkdssp')
```